# how to translate zend_parse_parameters from c++ to pascal?

Tags: php, pascal, freepascal

I need parse PHP extension parameters using lazarus/freepascal, but I do not know how to define the C function `zend_parse_parameters` in lazarus as:

```
int zend_parse_parameters ( int num_args TSRMLS_DC, char* type_spec, ... )
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is TSRMLS_DC ? Looks like some non standard C modifier

Comment: it is a PHP macro, PHP sample code as follow:        PHP_FUNCTION(exif_tagname)
{
 long tag;
 char *szTemp;

 if (zend_parse_parameters(ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "l", &tag) == FAILURE) {
  return;
 }

 szTemp = exif_get_tagname(tag, NULL, 0, tag_table_IFD TSRMLS_CC);

 if (tag < 0 || !szTemp || !szTemp[0]) {
  RETURN_FALSE;
 }

 RETURN_STRING(szTemp, 1)
}

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like

```
 uses ctypes;
 function zend_parse_parameters(num_args:cint;type_spec:pchar):cint;cdecl; varargs;
```

but I don't know what to do with the macro (I assume it is merely a helper macro that links together the variable part and the num_args).

Comment: yes,it is almost. i used this definition before, but it did not work, the error message was "PHP Warning:  encryptext() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/html/a.php on line 2". perhaps because the macro was missing.

Comment: That sounds like a problem on the PHP side. PHP can't know how the pascal side declares the parameter

Comment: so, the problem is how to send the parameter from the pascal side to PHP, the 2nd parameter of PHP macro "TSRMLS_CC" is missing.

Answer (score 0):

```
here is my test code of lazarus under CENTOS6.3:

procedure encryptext (ht : integer; return_value : pzval; this_ptr : pzval;
   return_value_used : integer; TSRMLS_DC : pointer); cdecl;
var
  getmyparameters: function(argu_num:integer;
                   type_apec:pansichar;Args : Array of const):integer;cdecl;
  a:integer;
  rtnstr:string;
begin
  if (PHPLib < 1) then exit;
  getmyparameters := GetProcAddress(PHPLib, 'zend_parse_parameters');
  if (@getmyparameters = nil) then
  begin
    raise EPHP4DelphiException.Create('zend_parse_parameters');
    exit;
  end;

  if ht < 1 then
  begin
   zend_wrong_param_count(TSRMLS_DC);
   Exit;
  end;

  a := 1;
  if (getmyparameters(ht,pansichar('s'),[pansichar(rtnstr),@a]) <> SUCCESS ) then exit;

  ZVAL_STRING(return_value,pansichar(rtnstr),true);
end;

php code of /var/www/html/a.php:
<?php
  echo encryptext('hello');
?>

the error message is:
PHP Warning:  encryptext() expects exactly 0 parameters, 1 given in /var/www/html/a.php on line 2
```